# Screenrecord causing phone framerate to drop

Tags: android, adb, performance-testing

I have a nexus running Lollipop and I tried to use the new options available to screenrecord,

I used

```
adb shell screenrecord --o raw-frames --bit-rate 4000000 /sdcard/output.raw
```

And the framerate went for a toss, the device became really sluggish, but If I use the default mp4 format it's actually faster.

Technically If I save the trouble of encoding shouldn't device performance be snappier? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: encoding is hardware accelerated anyway - so you get no measurable performance gain from not using compression. Instead the increased bitrate of the raw stream seems to max out the IO capacity of the storage subsystem.

Answer (score 0):

If I were you I would try remove the `raw-frames` argument since it can be a challenge for your device to keep up with the demand. 
Try using `adb shell screenrecord --bit-rate 4000000 --time-limit 30 /sdcard/output.mp4`

I don't think using the `.raw`-extension makes any difference actually